# How to prevent overlapping of a "position-fixed" element with variable size

Tags: html, css

I have a "position: fixed;" element which shall always be visible on the top of the page and contains contents with a variable height:

```
div.topfloat
{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

The problem is that it overlaps the content and the "top-padding:" property depends on the height of the "position: fixed" element.

Therefore I would need something like this:

```
div.content
{
    padding-top: [height of topfloat-element];
}
```

The HTML is rather simple:

```
<div class=topfloat>variable height</div>
<div class=contents>please don't overlap me</div>
```

Is there a way to solve it without using Javascript?

Comment: not that i know of, it really depend what your rest html is like.

Comment: There needs to be html we can look at to better understand your issue. Try jsfiddle.net

Comment: Are you trying to implement a sticky element?

Comment: I have added the HTML to the question; Yes I want to implement a sticky element, but it has unknown height

Answer (score 2):

Here is the non-Javascript solution, but it's not very pretty. The idea is to markup the *sticky* element twice, and set `visibility:hidden;` + `position:static;` on the cloned one.

```css
.top {
    position: fixed;
}
.top + .top {
    visibility: hidden;
    position: static;
}
```

```html
<div class="top">variable height</div>
<div class="top">variable height</div>
<div class="content">please don't overlap me</div>
```